# One-to-Many Storage Table SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am not asking about data types in this question as I do know IP addresses should be stored as BINARY(4) for IPv4--it's just a logical example. That being said, instead of storing ip addresses in a log table directly, I store all unique ip addresses (As they're added) to a `StoreIPAddress` table. Then I associate where needed by joining an ID field.

Example:

```
Table StoreIPAddress(ID INT Identity(1,1), IPAddress VARCHAR(15))
Table LogSessions(SessionID VARCHAR(255), IPAddressID)
```

So now, I don't have to store the ip address 50 billion times. I just store it once, and join via the ID field. I do this for many reoccurring values in the database.

I then use a stored procedure to get the ID if exists, and if not, add the ip address, and return the new ID. As so...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_StoreIPAddress] 
    @IPADDRESS VARCHAR(15), @ID INT OUTPUT
AS
    SET @ID = (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM dbo.StoreIPAddress WHERE IPAddress = @IPADDRESS);

    IF (ISNULL(@ID, 0) = 0)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dbo.StoreIPAddress(IPAddress) 
        VALUES(@IPADDRESS);

        SELECT @ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
    END
END
RETURN
```

This works if I am using it in a single instance, adding a session to the log, etc. But what if I'm running a script to add 100 ip addresses? A function would work perfectly, if I could write it just like the stored procedure. But functions cannot add data to a table.

This would be ideal:

```
UPDATE LogSessions
SET IPAddressID = dbo.udf_StoreIPAddress(IPAddress)
```

The problem is, this won't work due to functions not allowing insert statements. Is there another way around this? I can write cursors, and band-aids, but I'd like to figure out an efficient way to do this, securely and with best-practices in mind.

Comment: IP adress is just 32 bit integer (at least IPv4), so you should probably save it as just INT field.

Comment: Appropriate comment, but I'm only using ip address as an example. It could be email address, phone number, domain name, etc.

Comment: The example is bad in this case, since both the IPv4 and the IPV6 addresses are actually numbers by definition (the common representation of them is just for human readability). Furthermore, both of them are identifiers by definition. The e-mail address is a bad example too, since it is collected from the user and in most cases it is linked to the user, so you will use the user's ID as a reference in most cases (I know, historical data and special cases, and whatever).

Comment: I think you're missing the point. And yes, I store the user's ID when appropriate. But what if that user's email address changes? In an email log, you won't want to point to the user's ID. I'm not asking about data types, but thanks.

Comment: Why is a function more ideal?   You are still passing one IP to the function, so you are calling the function once per IP, same as with the procedure.   So what does making it a function get you?

Comment: Hi I deleted my answer, 'cause I think I missed the point... Is this correct: You want to log a new session. So you need the ID of the IP (or other source). If the actual IP does not exist, it should be created, otherwise fetched. With this ID you write the log entry?

Comment: You can't run a stored procedure as: UPDATE LogSessions SET IPAddressID = usp_GetIPAddress(IPAddressID) on multiple records. So I'd have to use a cursor if I am importing data to loop through each record to run the function.

Comment: Correct Shnugo, Add or fetch...

Comment: OK, had to do something else in the meanwhile... I posted another answer. There is IMHO no way to pack two depending DML statements into one single call. I had some ideas using MERGE and OUTPUT but didn't find something convincing. There is an answer already using a trigger. That was my other suggestion.

Comment: Hi Michael, is this question solved? Do you need further help?

Comment: No solution yet. I just have to split them up into two scripts which isn't a big deal, it just makes clear sense to me to be able to put this in one shot. I don't like storing data twice. For instance, I am doing this with domains for an email system. It's easier to get a domainID from a StoreDomains table for reporting, throttling, etc., instead of splitting the domain name from an email using a function. I'm testing this with a trigger, but haven't gotten it to work yet.

Comment: You don't like to store data twice... OK, this is something I'd say too. But isn't it exactly this what you are trying to do? If I understand your last comment correctly you might want to find or group eMails after their domain. Now you want to store the domains in an extra table and insert a `DomainID` to your original table. Why not add an indexed column to your original table, where you fill in the domain with a trigger or as computed column (be aware of `PERSISTED`!)  How many rows are there in your tables?

Answer (score 1):

This approach should do what you want. You might pack this into a SP. But if you want to pass in many rows at once you'd have to use a TYPE, an intermediate table (e.g. #Table) or XML:

```
DECLARE @ipAdr TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, IPAdr VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @ipAdr VALUES('8.8.8.8'),('192.168.0.12'),('10.15.0.3');

DECLARE @log TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, IPID INT, logDate DATETIME);

--Want to log a Date with IP '8.8.8.8' (existing) and one with '1.2.3.4' (new)

DECLARE @tblNewLogs TABLE(IPAdr VARCHAR(100),logDate DATETIME);
INSERT INTO @tblNewLogs VALUES('8.8.8.8',{d'2016-08-08'}),('1.2.3.4',{d'2016-01-02'});

INSERT INTO @ipAdr
SELECT IpAdr AS ip
FROM @tblNewLogs AS nl
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @ipAdr AS x WHERE x.IPAdr=nl.IPAdr);

INSERT INTO @log
SELECT ip.ID,nl.logDate
FROM @tblNewLogs AS nl
INNER JOIN @ipAdr AS ip ON nl.IPAdr=ip.IPAdr;

SELECT * FROM @ipAdr;
SELECT * FROM @log;
```

Comment: I was thinking of this as an alternative to my trigger approach

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `VIEW` with an `INSTEAD OF INSERT TRIGGER` on the View and INSERT INTO the View:

```
CREATE Table StoreIPAddress(ID INT Identity(1,1), IPAddress VARCHAR(15));

CREATE Table LogSessions(SessionID VARCHAR(255), IPAddressID INT);
GO
CREATE VIEW vwStoreIpAddress
AS
SELECT s.IpAddress, LS.SessionId
FROM StoreIpAddress S
INNER JOIN LogSessions LS
  ON S.ID = LS.IPAddressId

GO
CREATE TRIGGER trgvwStoreIpAddress ON vwStoreIpAddress
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS

    INSERT INTO StoreIPAddress (IPAddress)
    SELECT I.IPAddress
    FROM INSERTED I
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM StoreIPAddress S WHERE S.IPAddress = I.IPAddress)

    INSERT INTO LogSessions (SessionId, IPAddressID)
    SELECT i.SessionID, S.ID
    FROM inserted I
    INNER JOIN StoreIPAddress S
        ON I.IPAddress = S.IPAddress
```

Then a simple insert statement:

```
 INSERT INTO vwStoreIpAddress
 SELECT '1.1.1.1', 'session1'
 UNION ALL
 SELECT '1.1.1.1', 'session2'
 UNION ALL
 SELECT '1.1.1.2', 'session1'
```

Comment: voted this, as especially the intuitive and easy calls are really convincing. I do not like triggers and try to avoid them, but in this case I could go with it...